# Push notification is not working in some Android devices

Tags: android, push-notification

I developed an Android app for push notification. The targeted SDK is 23 and the minimum SDK is 11. I  tested the app in **Huawei P6 (4.2.2)** and it runs smoothly, but I tested it with **Huawei Y360 (4.4.2)** and app does not work - push notification is neither sent or received.

This is my dependencies:
[image]

I carried out following actions:

- Wifi connected
- sim card, checked
- push notification enabled.
- API level fulfills the minimum required level.

But still does not work for the device. Is there any generous mind to help me with this? Spend almost two days, searched everywhere without vain and posted the question here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Google gcm library?

Comment: I have updated the question above to how the libraries I have included.

Answer (score 0):

I faced problems like this sometimes (when push notification work on one device and doesn't work on other) and always the problem was in code.

1) If you are using gcm library try to check if your device register in gmc system, maybe problem is on this step.

2) I don't know how u testing push notifications (have u 2 physical devices or emulator), but u can try to clean project before build.

3) Also the problem can be on server side of ur app.